# Migrate SQL Server DateTime column to DateTimeOffset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetimeoffset

I have an old table with a few rows that has a datetime column. I want to switch this to `datetimeoffset` but I want to be able to transfer the data that already exists. So I'm doing something like:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_Temp ON

INSERT INTO Table_Temp
    (Col0, ... ColN,)
SELECT 
    COl0,.... ColN, from 
Table_Original;
    
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_Temp OFF
```

This works but the offset set is 0 when I do the `datetime` to `datetimeoffset` assignment. Fortunately the offset that I want to set it to is the offset of the current system. I can't seem to figure out an easy way to do this.

I want to be able to set the offset within the conversion. I was going to resort to doing a C# utility(or PowerShell) but I would rather keep it simple.

Comment: ---

Thanks guys, i should have been clear in that i simply wanted to add the offset without changing the time itself. But you guys got me there! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a version of SQL Server that knows of the datetimeoffset type, this syntax will work for getting you the local tz offset of the server:

`select datepart(tz,sysdatetimeoffset())`

The result is in MINUTES.

Comment: Thanks for that, exactly what I needed. They're using so many overlapping terms now that it's become difficult to even search the docs…

Answer (score 22):

See below for doc, you probably want something like:

```
-- up here set the @time_zone variable.

INSERT INTO Table_Temp
    (Col0, ... ColN,)
SELECT 
    COl0, TODATETIMEOFFSET(COLDATE, @time_zone),.... ColN, from 
Table_Original;
```

From [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721270.aspx)

> The SWITCHOFFSET function adjusts an
>   input DATETIMEOFFSET value to a
>   specified time zone, while preserving
>   the UTC value. The syntax is
>   SWITCHOFFSET(datetimeoffset_value,
>   time_zone). For example, the following
>   code adjusts the current system
>   datetimeoffset value to time zone GMT
>   +05:00:
>
> SELECT
>   SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),
>   '-05:00');
>
> So if the current system
>   datetimeoffset value is February 12,
>   2009 10:00:00.0000000 -08:00, this
>   code returns the value February 12,
>   2009 13:00:00.0000000 -05:00.
>
> The TODATETIMEOFFSET function sets the
>   time zone offset of an input date and
>   time value. Its syntax is
>   TODATETIMEOFFSET(date_and_time_value,
>   time_zone).
>
> This function is different from
>   SWITCHOFFSET in several ways. First,
>   it is not restricted to a
>   datetimeoffset value as input; rather
>   it accepts any date and time data
>   type. Second, it does not try to
>   adjust the time based on the time zone
>   difference between the source value
>   and the specified time zone but
>   instead simply returns the input date
>   and time value with the specified time
>   zone as a datetimeoffset value.
>
> The main purpose of the
>   TODATETIMEOFFSET function is to
>   convert types that are not time zone
>   aware to DATETIMEOFFSET by the given
>   time zone offset. If the given date
>   and time value is a DATETIMEOFFSET,
>   the TODATETIMEOFFSET function changes
>   the DATETIMEOFFSET value based on the
>   same original local date and time
>   value plus the new given time zone
>   offset.
>
> For example, the current system
>   datetimeoffset value is February 12,
>   2009 10:00:00.0000000 -08:00, and you
>   run the following code:
>
> SELECT
>   TODATETIMEOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),
>   '-05:00');
>
> The value February 12, 2009
>   10:00:00.0000000 -05:00 is returned.
>   Remember that the SWITCHOFFSET
>   function returned February 12, 2009
>   13:00:00.0000000 -05:00 because it
>   adjusted the time based on the time
>   zone differences between the input
>   (-08:00) and the specified time zone
>   (-05:00).
>
> As mentioned earlier, you can use the
>   TODATETIMEOFFSET function with any
>   date and time data type as input. For
>   example, the following code takes the
>   current system date and time value and
>   returns it as a datetimeoffset value
>   with a time zone -00:05:
>
> SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(SYSDATETIME(),
>   '-05:00');

Comment: One comment on this v. old post. Timezone and offset of date time are to different things. Timezone takes into account DST while offset is just offset.

Answer (score 3):

These conversions functions will not work correctly if DST saving is active in the target timezone, as the timezone offset changes inside the same year.

Comment: How would you do it correctly, to take into account DST?

Comment: Not really answer - more suited to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out what the offset of the current SQL server is using the following.

```
select datediff(MI,getdate(), getutcdate())
```

You need to get the offset in minutes and not hours since there are a number of half hour and even a quarter hour time zone.

Using the minutes value, you can alter your values going in (assuming they were historically all recorded as local time) by using something like

```
select dateadd(mi,datediff(MI,getdate(), getutcdate()), yourDateField)
```

For efficiency I would calculate it once into a variable and use that, since the difference is not going to change.

Comment: this doesn't work on historical dates if you need to account for daylight savings time. Right? You're finding your current UTC offset based on getdate and then adding this to a historical date field. But, the offset changes if you want to account for DST. Eastern standard time is UTC-5, but Eastern Daylight time is UTC-4. If you want to convert historical dates you have to be aware of the daylight saving transitions. (I get a headache just thinking about it).

Comment: Correct you would, and then shift the historical data in batches, then account for eacy year having a different point in time that it shifted.

Comment: How would you go about finding the offset of the historical date?

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variation of an answer already provided, and does NOT account for DST changes. However, it might be good enough for many purposes:

```
dateadd(minute, -datepart(tz, sysdatetimeoffset()), @legacyDatetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to solve this problem correctly, accounting for DST here is the tool to do it.

https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport